# About "The very first time" phrase

Tags: sentence-construction

I want to express my idea diversely. So I want to know these are all possible to use.

> 1. My first few weeks with my girlfriend, I was so nervous that I made a lot of mistakes.

I think it is possible without any doubts.

> 2. The first few weeks that I spent with my girlfriend, I was so nervous that I made a lot of mistakes.

yes, possible to use

> 3. The first few weeks, when My girlfriend and I were new to each other, I was so nervous that I made a lot of mistakes.

Here, 'when ...each other' clause specify 'the first few weeks'. So I think it is possible. and 'were new to each other' could mean some specific time 'period' not a time point, which make sense with 'first few weeks'(time period)

> 4. The first few weeks, when I started to date her, I was so nervous that I made a lot of mistakes.

I don't think it's possible because 'the first few weeks' represents duration, but 'started to date' represent a specific time point.

Comment: These would all be fine. Just check my edit that corrected errors to do with time. In English you can not say "the first few weeks", but you must say "in the first few weeks" or "during the first few weeks".

Comment: Actually, you can say "the first few weeks," exactly as Jihoon put it. The only edit needed is:  "stared to date" --> "**started** to date"

Answer (score 1):

All of these options are acceptable, but the first and second ones are probably the best.  In some cases, like the one in your last example, an action doesn't happen at one specific time, but naturally and slowly grows over a somewhat longer period of time.  You don't really start dating someone at one specific moment:  it is a process, not an event.

Answer (score 0):

Any of them would be fine and correct with one edit: in #3 you wouldn't capitalise 'my'.

Alternatively, and somewhat easier on the ear:

> For the first few weeks I was dating my girlfriend, I was so nervous that
>   I made a lot of mistakes.